# Fill empty space inside a CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android-coordinatorlayout, bottom-sheet

I'm trying to have a bottom sheet layout that will always appear on the screen.
I know I have to use the CoordinatorLayout if i want to use the "app:layout_behaviour" and also the CoordinatorLayout must have a match_parent height so when i'll expand the bottom sheet then it will go all the way to the top.

The problem is that while I want the bottom sheet layout to always appear on the bottom of screen I also need a ScrollView to contain different views, BUT it has to "fill" the empty space between the top of the screen to the top of the bottom sheet layout.
I know its possible to use 0dp to match constraints with ConstraintLayout but that wont work here because bottom sheet behaviour must be used with CoordinatorLayout. How can I achieve it?
Below is the basic code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <!--        THIS LAYOUT'S HEIGHT MUST FILL THE SPACE BETWEEN THE TOP OF THE SCREEN TO THE TOP OF 
                    THE BOTTOM SHEET-->
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >

        <!--        Some layouts that the user can scroll-->
        <!--        Some layouts that the user can scroll-->

    </ScrollView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_bottom_fragment"
        android:elevation="30dp"
        app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/bottom_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <View
                android:layout_width="48dp"
                android:layout_height="6dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_button" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Sheet title"
                android:textSize="17sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/bottom_view"
            android:background="@color/recyclerViewBgColor"
            app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
            android:paddingTop="12dp"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Any kind of help is appreciated!